# Sorting data using Datatables on Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

I'm using Datatables on my Laravel project to show stock of products, but when I tried to sort it, it's error

This is my script in view

```
@section('script')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var oTable = $('#stock-table').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: '{{ url("stock-data") }}'
                },columns: [
                    {data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at'},
                    {data: 'product_name', name: 'product_name'},
                    {data: 'unit_stock', name: 'unit_stock'},
                    {data: 'status', name: 'status'},
                ],
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

And this is my controller

```
public function stock()
    {
        return view('stock-report');
    }

    public function stockData()
    {
        $stock = Products::all();
        return Datatables::of($stock)
//            ->orderColumn('unit_stock $1')
            ->addColumn('status', function ($stock) {
                if ($stok->unit_stock == 0)
                    return '<span class="label label-danger">EMPTY</span>';
                else
                    return '<span class="label label-success">NOT EMPTY</span>';
            })
            ->make(true);
    }
```

It's error when I add `->orderColumn('unit_stock $1')`, is there any solution, big thanks

Comment: It would help if you posted the error. You could probably find this by using developer tools and checking the response or in your laravel.log file.

Comment: It says `DataTables warning: table id=tabel-stok - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7`

Comment: If you go to http://datatables.net/tn/7 and go to diagnosis it will show you how to see the actual error. This assumes you have debug set to true in your .env file, otherwise the error should be in your laravel log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to sort the Datatable adding : **order**

```
$('#stock-table').DataTable( {
.
.
.
       "order": [[ numberColum, "desc" ]],
.
.
} );
```

also you can try to order in the select:

```
Products::orderBy('unit_stock', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works, I've been using `Products::orderBy('unit_stock', 'DESC')->get();` but the result just sorting the first data and the next one is randomize